# ElasticSearch: mget doesn't work even thought get works

Tags: elasticsearch

I've tried to use `_mget` api using http straightforwardly:

```
curl -u elastic:changeme -XGET localhost:9200/index/_mget?pretty -d '
{
  "docs": [
    {
      "_type": "coll",
      "_id": "1474c1a0-2540-11e7-9271-0242ac110008"
    }
  ]
}
'
```

and I'm getting a not exists response:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "_index" : "index",
      "_type" : "coll",
      "_id" : "1474c1a0-2540-11e7-9271-0242ac110008",
      "found" : false
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I've tried to get this document using `get` api:

```
curl -u elastic:changeme -XGET localhost:9200/index/coll/1474c1a0-2540-11e7-9271-0242ac110008?pretty
```

and the response I'm getting is right:

```
{
  "_index" : "index",
  "_type" : "coll",
  "_id" : "1474c1a0-2540-11e7-9271-0242ac110008",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_routing" : "user",
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "user" : "user",
    "timestamp" : "2017-04-18T22:00:00Z",
    "startTimestamp" : "2017-04-18T22:00:00Z",
    "dueTimestamp" : null,
    "closingTimestamp" : null,
    "matter" : "Activity 16",
    "comment" : null,
    "status" : 20,
    "backlogStatus" : 20,
    "metainfos" : {
      "fbcbeacfbcbeacfbcbeacfbcbeacfbcbaeac" : [
        "Project A"
      ],
      "fceceacfcedeacfceeeacfcefeacfcfeac" : [
        "Example activity"
      ],
      "ffceacffceacffceacffceacffceac" : [
        "Marketing"
      ],
      "efeacefeacefeacefeacefeac" : [
        "2017-Q3"
      ],
      "ddfceacddfceacddfceacddfceacddfceac" : [
        "West"
      ],
      "eaaeaceabeaceaceaceadeaceaeeac" : [
        "2-Important - Not urgent"
      ],
      "eaceeaceaceeaceaceaeaceacebeaceaceceac" : [
        "4-Completed"
      ],
      "efeeeacefefeaceffeaceffeaceffeac" : [
        "Oliver"
      ]
    },
    "resources" : [ ],
    "notes" : null
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a dejavu with this post. Didn't you ask the same question few days ago and @Val provided an answer?

Comment: Did you change anything to the mget query before pasting it? Such as the index name, server url etc?

Comment: It looks like your document has a weird routing. Is it normal? Do you have multiple shards? Can you try your mget query specifying the routing?

Comment: Indeed, @AndreiStefan I have the same feeling :-)

Comment: Sorry, I removed the latest one in order to clean up some approaches a I wrote out. I posed some issues I think now are only realted with `mget` doesn't work and `get` do it.

Comment: I'm creating aliases for each user. So each user has a query associated. But I think the problem is not related with it. Both (`mget` and `get` are gettig over the same environment)...